# TrueCrypt Encryption Tool

Tags: truecrypt

We are planning to use the open source tool TrueCrypt for USB flash drive encryption. Anyone want to share their opinion/feedback about adavantages/disadvantages for it and want to share with us, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for any replies.

Hemal

Answer (score 3):

Essentially a great product. Secure, fast and reliable. The only drawback I can think of is that key management is a a bit of a hassle compared to the commercial products. Eg. if you want to be able to recover data for a user that has lost her password.

Answer (score 1):

For those of us managing enterprise environments, TrueCrypt requires administrator rights when you insert the thumb drive into the computer.  Not ideal.

Comment: Is that true even if Truecrypt is already installed on that system?

Comment: I don't believe so.  This doesn't work for me because I was looking for a solution that would run right from the USB drive for my end users who don't have admin rights on their workstations.

Comment: Documentation confirms that once installed, a non-admin can use.  http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=non-admin-users

Comment: @Will M - While it's true that you can run it without admin rights, you can only do that if TC is installed on the workstation by an admin.  We were looking for a completely portable solution via thumb drives and TC will NOT run in portable mode without admin rights.

Comment: Agree that is an unfortunate limitation on TrueCrypt.  Please post back if you find an alternative without that issue!

Answer (score 0):

Wonderful product. I have used it for USB drives and full HD encryption and have yet to run into any frustrations.

I even [recommended it](https://superuser.com/questions/52371/how-to-replace-the-dell-diagnostics-boot-option-with-a-small-linux/52375#52375) earlier today on superuser.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used TrueCrypt to secure an entire drive or device but I do offer one caution. I had a TrueCrypt file become corrupted and unrecoverable just one time when using the Mac version to open a 40GB file created by the Windows version. This may not have been a TrueCrypt issue though, as I had done the same a number of times previously. Still, it prevents me from repeating the exercise.